# Roxin's Condition

Tags: convex-analysis, optimal-control

I am currently working on weak optimal controls and I got stuck on the so called roxin's condtion. The condition stats in my case that the set

$$M:=\lbrace (f(u), |u|^2 |u\in U\rbrace,$$

where f(u) is linear in u, |.| is the euklidian norm of u and U is a convex compact set, is also convex.
However, I struggel to show that the set $M$ is convex. For f it is easy because of the linearity it is an affine mapping however for the quadratic part I am unsure.
This is how far I got:
We have to show that for $\lambda \in [0, 1]$ and $m,m'\in M$,
 $$\lambda m +(1-\lambda)m' \in M$$
\begin{align}
\lambda \begin{pmatrix}f(u)\\
|u|^2
\end{pmatrix} +(1-\lambda)\begin{pmatrix}f(u')\\
|u'|^2
\end{pmatrix}
=\begin{pmatrix}
f(\lambda u+(1-\lambda)u')\\
\lambda u^2+(1-\lambda)|u'|^2
\end{pmatrix},
\end{align}
where $\lambda u+(1-\lambda)u'\in U$ because U is convex. However, I can not get it to work for the square of the norm. Maybe somebody has an idea.

Big thanks in advance!

Comment: Without further assumptions, this is false. Take $U = [0, 1] \subseteq \Bbb{R}$ and $f : \Bbb{R} \to \Bbb{R} : x \mapsto x$. Then $M$ is a non-trivial subset of the graph of $y = x^2$, a non-convex curve. Did you mean instead, $$M:=\{(f(u), \alpha) \mid u \in U, \alpha \ge |u|^2\}?$$

Comment: great counter example! Thank You. I actually try to understand why the roxin condtion is a generalisation of the LQ problems. However, this shows that it is probably not applicable here.

Answer (score 1):

In general your set, which is like $\{(x,x^2),\ x\in[0,1]\}$, will not be convex; however if your problem is comming from an optimisation problem, I think it is sometimes only needed that an other set be convex (assuming that you can recast you original problem into an equivalent one with adding a control $\eta\geq 0$) that is,
the set $\{(x,x^2+\eta),\ x\in[0,1], \eta\geq 0\}$ be convex
or possibly
$\{(x, (x^2+\eta)\wedge 1),\ x\in[0,1], \eta\geq 0\}$ be convex
(and these sets are indeed convex).